# Saxon-CE_1.1 set-attribute doesn't update an input element's attribute once it's value has been manually changed

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm quite new to XSLT and using the Saxon CE processor. I am writing a transformation where a submit button's onclick event writes the 'checked' state of a checkbox to a text field. It works fine as long as the text is not manually edited. Once the text is edited manually, any subsequent onclick events fail to write the checkbox status to the text field.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is a code snippet of the xsl file. Would really appreciate any help or suggestions in solving this riddle that I've spent a day pondering over.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="chk1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Show Selection" name="btnShowText"/>
    <input name="txtResult"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//input[@name='btnShowText']" mode="ixsl:onclick">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//input[@name='txtResult']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//input[@name='txtResult']">
    <ixsl:set-attribute name="value" select="//input[@name='chk1']/@prop:checked"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I do wish people wouldn't downvote questions without saying why. I can't see anything here that deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript as well as with Saxon, to manipulate a form control you need to set the property of the control, not the attribute, so use `ixsl:set‑property`

```
<xsl:template match="//input[@name='txtResult']">
    <ixsl:set-property object="." name="value" select="//input[@name='chk1']/@prop:checked"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response .. thanks for the suggestion, it worked

Answer (score 0):

First, note that Saxon-CE is being superseded by Saxon-JS.

Second, ixsl:set-attribute has delayed effect - the update is only made when the current transformation phase (that is, the processing of the onclick event) finishes.

But having said that, I'm not sure this gets to the bottom of it. One thing I have often found confusing in this area is the distinction between attributes in the HTML DOM (such as value) and the underlying properties (such as the checked property), which aren't always in sync.

Does debugging show that the onclick template is actually executed?

Answer (score 0):

With Saxon-JS, the following seems to work (after changing the name attributes to id attributes in the HTML):

```
<xsl:template match="*[@id='btnShowText']" mode="ixsl:onclick">
  <ixsl:set-property name="value" object="id('txtResult',ixsl:page())"
    select="ixsl:get(id('chk1',ixsl:page()), 'checked')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I didn’t get any other variant to work, in particular the apply-templates of `//input[@id='txtResult']` was not evaluated / did not match. I suspected that it was due to my namespaced HTML source, but also `*:input` did not match.